# Turn SVG with Mask and Symbols to a plain SVG file?

Tags: xml, image, svg, converters

I was trying to take a SVG from a page, but this one wasn't that easy. It contains `<mask>` and `<symbol>` tag and for some reason, it's inside a `<html>` tag.

This is the SVG I got:

https://pastebin.com/fF0U2TLw (test it from here)

```
<html>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0" id="__SVG_SPRITE_NODE__">
    <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 42 42" fill="none" id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a">
        <g filter="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_filter0_i)">
            <path d="M13.865 4.666a.936.936 0 0 1 .662-.274h12.924c.249 0 .487.098.662.274l9.14 9.139a.936.936 0 0 1 .273.662V27.39a.936.936 0 0 1-.274.662l-9.139 9.139a.936.936 0 0 1-.662.274H14.527a.936.936 0 0 1-.662-.274l-9.139-9.139a.936.936 0 0 1-.274-.662V14.467c0-.248.099-.487.274-.662l9.14-9.139z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint0_linear)"></path>
        </g>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14.222 4.636l-9.585 9.586v13.556l9.585 9.585h13.556l9.585-9.585V14.222l-9.585-9.586H14.222zM13.447.892c-.497 0-.973.197-1.324.548L1.44 12.122a1.872 1.872 0 0 0-.548 1.324v15.107c0 .497.197.973.548 1.324l10.683 10.682c.35.351.827.549 1.324.549h15.106c.497 0 .973-.198 1.324-.549L40.56 29.877c.35-.351.548-.827.548-1.324V13.446c0-.496-.197-.973-.548-1.324L29.877 1.44a1.872 1.872 0 0 0-1.324-.548H13.446z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint1_linear)"></path>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14.222 4.636l-9.585 9.586v13.556l9.585 9.585h13.556l9.585-9.585V14.222l-9.585-9.586H14.222zM13.447.892c-.497 0-.973.197-1.324.548L1.44 12.122a1.872 1.872 0 0 0-.548 1.324v15.107c0 .497.197.973.548 1.324l10.683 10.682c.35.351.827.549 1.324.549h15.106c.497 0 .973-.198 1.324-.549L40.56 29.877c.35-.351.548-.827.548-1.324V13.446c0-.496-.197-.973-.548-1.324L29.877 1.44a1.872 1.872 0 0 0-1.324-.548H13.446z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint2_linear)" fill-opacity=".3"></path>
        <g filter="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_filter1_d)">
            <path d="M32.324 17.505l-5.943 4.349-1.203-3.722a.559.559 0 0 1 .532-.731h6.58c.056 0 .079.071.034.104z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint3_linear)"></path>
            <path d="M32.324 17.505l-5.943 4.349-1.203-3.722a.559.559 0 0 1 .532-.731h6.58c.056 0 .079.071.034.104z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint4_linear)" fill-opacity=".2"></path>
            <path d="M32.324 17.505l-5.943 4.349-1.203-3.722a.559.559 0 0 1 .532-.731h6.58c.056 0 .079.071.034.104z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint5_linear)" fill-opacity=".3"></path>
            <path d="M21.06 9.26c.021-.065.098.006.12.072l6.896 21.344.001.006c.01.05-.045.089-.088.06v-.002L9.903 17.505c-.044-.033-.021-.104.034-.104h8.455a.057.057 0 0 0 .054-.04l2.613-8.1z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint6_linear)"></path>
            <path d="M21.06 9.26c.021-.065.098.006.12.072l6.896 21.344.001.006c.01.05-.045.089-.088.06v-.002L9.903 17.505c-.044-.033-.021-.104.034-.104h8.455a.057.057 0 0 0 .054-.04l2.613-8.1z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint7_linear)" fill-opacity=".2"></path>
            <path d="M21.06 9.26c.021-.065.098.006.12.072l6.896 21.344.001.006c.01.05-.045.089-.088.06v-.002L9.903 17.505c-.044-.033-.021-.104.034-.104h8.455a.057.057 0 0 0 .054-.04l2.613-8.1z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint8_linear)" fill-opacity=".3"></path>
            <path d="M17.033 24.138a.559.559 0 0 0-.862.28l-2.018 6.258c-.017.053.043.097.087.064l5.907-4.323-3.114-2.279z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint9_linear)"></path>
            <path d="M17.033 24.138a.559.559 0 0 0-.862.28l-2.018 6.258c-.017.053.043.097.087.064l5.907-4.323-3.114-2.279z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint10_linear)" fill-opacity=".2"></path>
            <path d="M17.033 24.138a.559.559 0 0 0-.862.28l-2.018 6.258c-.017.053.043.097.087.064l5.907-4.323-3.114-2.279z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint11_linear)" fill-opacity=".3"></path>
        </g>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M32.324 17.505c.045-.033.022-.104-.033-.104H25.71c-.38 0-.649.37-.532.73l1.203 3.723 5.943-4.35zm-1.29.364H25.71a.09.09 0 0 0-.087.119l1.005 3.106 4.406-3.225zM21.06 9.26l-2.613 8.101a.057.057 0 0 1-.054.04H9.938c-.055 0-.078.071-.034.104L27.947 30.71l.007.005.034.025.002.001c.042.03.098-.01.087-.059v-.003l-.001-.003-.013-.038L21.18 9.331a.172.172 0 0 0-.018-.04c-.032-.049-.084-.084-.101-.032zm.049 1.375l6.131 18.978-16.045-11.744h7.198c.23 0 .43-.15.5-.364M14.24 30.74c-.044.033-.104-.011-.087-.064l.012-.039 2.006-6.22a.559.559 0 0 1 .862-.279l3.114 2.279-5.907 4.323zm.747-1.127l4.368-3.196-2.598-1.901a.09.09 0 0 0-.14.045l-1.63 5.052z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint12_linear)" fill-opacity=".2"></path>
        <defs>
            <filter id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_filter0_i" x="4.452" y="4.392" width="33.074" height="34.478" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"></feFlood>
                <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"></feBlend>
                <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"></feColorMatrix>
                <feOffset dy="1.404"></feOffset>
                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=".936"></feGaussianBlur>
                <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"></feComposite>
                <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.45 0"></feColorMatrix>
                <feBlend in2="shape" result="effect1_innerShadow"></feBlend>
            </filter>
            <filter id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_filter1_d" x="7.541" y="7.362" width="27.147" height="26.198" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"></feFlood>
                <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"></feColorMatrix>
                <feOffset dy=".468"></feOffset>
                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.17"></feGaussianBlur>
                <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.9 0"></feColorMatrix>
                <feBlend in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"></feBlend>
                <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"></feBlend>
            </filter>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint0_linear" x1="14.139" y1="4.392" x2="14.139" y2="39.645" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#732600"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#260D00"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#401500"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint1_linear" x1="12.671" y1=".892" x2="29.329" y2="41.108" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#FD6E35"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F50"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint2_linear" x1="-1.82" y1="-2.013" x2="21.114" y2="20.922" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="red"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint3_linear" x1="21.114" y1="9.221" x2="21.114" y2="30.751" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#FD6E35"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F50"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint4_linear" x1="21.114" y1="9.221" x2="21.114" y2="15.54" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#fff"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint5_linear" x1="14.778" y1="5.151" x2="20.733" y2="20.152" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="red"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint6_linear" x1="21.114" y1="9.221" x2="21.114" y2="30.751" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#FD6E35"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F50"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint7_linear" x1="21.114" y1="9.221" x2="21.114" y2="15.54" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#fff"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint8_linear" x1="14.778" y1="5.151" x2="20.733" y2="20.152" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="red"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint9_linear" x1="21.114" y1="9.221" x2="21.114" y2="30.751" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#FD6E35"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F50"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint10_linear" x1="21.114" y1="9.221" x2="21.114" y2="15.54" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#fff"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint11_linear" x1="14.778" y1="5.151" x2="20.733" y2="20.152" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="red"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint12_linear" x1="27.901" y1="10.859" x2="14.093" y2="30.751" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#fff"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
    </symbol>
    <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 16" fill="none" id="f_icon_efa5fa29">
        <path d="M21.82 0H2.18C.977 0 0 .97 0 2.165v11.67C0 15.03.976 16 2.18 16h19.64c1.204 0 2.18-.97 2.18-2.165V2.165A2.173 2.173 0 0 0 21.82 0z" fill="#4758A9"></path>
        <path d="M4.457 0h12.686v16L4.457 0z" fill="#FFC700"></path>
        <path d="M2.5 1.617c-.093-.027-.097-.082 0-.123l.342-.15a.317.317 0 0 0 .168-.248v-.34c0-.096.059-.113.12-.041l.23.272c.07.075.177.102.274.068l.37-.146c.09-.038.124 0 .07.082l-.213.34a.267.267 0 0 0 0 .286l.222.29c.059.074.028.122-.065.105l-.363-.068a.303.303 0 0 0-.274.109l-.189.259c-.058.078-.113.064-.123-.031l-.038-.34a.287.287 0 0 0-.189-.222L2.5 1.617zM3.98 3.49c-.092-.028-.095-.082 0-.123l.343-.15a.313.313 0 0 0 .168-.248v-.34c0-.096.059-.113.12-.042l.23.273c.07.075.178.102.274.068l.37-.147c.09-.034.12 0 .07.082l-.213.34a.267.267 0 0 0 0 .287l.223.289c.058.075.027.123-.066.105l-.363-.068a.303.303 0 0 0-.274.11l-.189.258c-.058.078-.113.065-.123-.03l-.041-.341a.286.286 0 0 0-.189-.221l-.34-.102zm1.485 1.872c-.093-.028-.096-.082 0-.123l.343-.15a.313.313 0 0 0 .168-.248V4.5c0-.096.058-.113.12-.041l.23.275c.07.075.177.102.274.068l.37-.146c.09-.037.12 0 .069.082l-.213.34a.267.267 0 0 0 0 .286l.223.29c.058.074.027.122-.065.105l-.364-.068a.303.303 0 0 0-.274.109l-.188.259c-.055.078-.114.064-.124-.031l-.038-.34a.287.287 0 0 0-.188-.222l-.343-.105zM6.95 7.234c-.093-.027-.096-.081 0-.122l.342-.15a.313.313 0 0 0 .168-.249v-.34c0-.095.059-.112.12-.04l.23.275c.07.075.178.102.274.068l.37-.146c.09-.035.12 0 .07.081l-.213.34a.267.267 0 0 0 0 .287l.223.289c.058.075.027.123-.066.106l-.363-.069a.303.303 0 0 0-.274.11l-.189.258c-.058.078-.113.065-.123-.03l-.041-.341a.283.283 0 0 0-.189-.221l-.34-.106zm1.484 1.872c-.092-.027-.096-.081 0-.122l.343-.15a.317.317 0 0 0 .168-.249v-.34c0-.095.058-.112.12-.04l.23.275c.07.075.177.102.274.068l.37-.146c.09-.038.12 0 .069.081l-.213.34a.267.267 0 0 0 0 .287l.223.29c.058.074.028.122-.065.105l-.363-.069a.303.303 0 0 0-.275.11l-.188.258c-.058.078-.113.065-.124-.03l-.04-.34a.283.283 0 0 0-.19-.222l-.339-.106zm1.485 1.873c-.093-.027-.096-.082 0-.123l.343-.15a.317.317 0 0 0 .168-.248v-.34c0-.096.058-.113.12-.041l.23.275a.26.26 0 0 0 .274.069l.37-.147c.09-.037.12 0 .069.082l-.213.34a.267.267 0 0 0 0 .286l.223.29c.058.075.027.122-.065.105l-.364-.068a.303.303 0 0 0-.274.109l-.189.259c-.058.078-.113.064-.123-.03l-.041-.341a.287.287 0 0 0-.189-.222l-.34-.105zm1.484 1.875c-.092-.027-.096-.081 0-.122l.343-.15a.317.317 0 0 0 .168-.248v-.341c0-.095.059-.116.12-.04l.23.275c.07.075.177.102.274.068l.37-.146c.09-.038.12 0 .07.081l-.213.34a.267.267 0 0 0 0 .287l.223.29c.058.074.027.122-.066.105l-.363-.069a.303.303 0 0 0-.274.11l-.189.258c-.058.079-.113.065-.123-.03l-.042-.34a.286.286 0 0 0-.188-.222l-.34-.106zm1.272 1.604c-.092-.027-.096-.082 0-.123l.343-.15a.317.317 0 0 0 .168-.248v-.34c0-.096.059-.113.12-.041l.23.276c.07.074.177.101.274.068l.37-.147c.09-.037.12 0 .073.082l-.213.34a.268.268 0 0 0 0 .286l.223.29c.058.075.03.122-.065.105l-.364-.068a.303.303 0 0 0-.274.109l-.189.259c-.054.078-.113.064-.123-.03l-.041-.341a.286.286 0 0 0-.189-.222l-.343-.105z" fill="#fff"></path>
    </symbol>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 42 42" fill="none" id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a">
    <g filter="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_filter0_i)">
        <path d="M13.865 4.666a.936.936 0 0 1 .662-.274h12.924c.249 0 .487.098.662.274l9.14 9.139a.936.936 0 0 1 .273.662V27.39a.936.936 0 0 1-.274.662l-9.139 9.139a.936.936 0 0 1-.662.274H14.527a.936.936 0 0 1-.662-.274l-9.139-9.139a.936.936 0 0 1-.274-.662V14.467c0-.248.099-.487.274-.662l9.14-9.139z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint0_linear)"></path>
    </g>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14.222 4.636l-9.585 9.586v13.556l9.585 9.585h13.556l9.585-9.585V14.222l-9.585-9.586H14.222zM13.447.892c-.497 0-.973.197-1.324.548L1.44 12.122a1.872 1.872 0 0 0-.548 1.324v15.107c0 .497.197.973.548 1.324l10.683 10.682c.35.351.827.549 1.324.549h15.106c.497 0 .973-.198 1.324-.549L40.56 29.877c.35-.351.548-.827.548-1.324V13.446c0-.496-.197-.973-.548-1.324L29.877 1.44a1.872 1.872 0 0 0-1.324-.548H13.446z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint1_linear)"></path>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14.222 4.636l-9.585 9.586v13.556l9.585 9.585h13.556l9.585-9.585V14.222l-9.585-9.586H14.222zM13.447.892c-.497 0-.973.197-1.324.548L1.44 12.122a1.872 1.872 0 0 0-.548 1.324v15.107c0 .497.197.973.548 1.324l10.683 10.682c.35.351.827.549 1.324.549h15.106c.497 0 .973-.198 1.324-.549L40.56 29.877c.35-.351.548-.827.548-1.324V13.446c0-.496-.197-.973-.548-1.324L29.877 1.44a1.872 1.872 0 0 0-1.324-.548H13.446z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint2_linear)" fill-opacity=".3"></path>
    <g filter="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_filter1_d)">
        <path d="M32.324 17.505l-5.943 4.349-1.203-3.722a.559.559 0 0 1 .532-.731h6.58c.056 0 .079.071.034.104z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint3_linear)"></path>
        <path d="M32.324 17.505l-5.943 4.349-1.203-3.722a.559.559 0 0 1 .532-.731h6.58c.056 0 .079.071.034.104z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint4_linear)" fill-opacity=".2"></path>
        <path d="M32.324 17.505l-5.943 4.349-1.203-3.722a.559.559 0 0 1 .532-.731h6.58c.056 0 .079.071.034.104z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint5_linear)" fill-opacity=".3"></path>
        <path d="M21.06 9.26c.021-.065.098.006.12.072l6.896 21.344.001.006c.01.05-.045.089-.088.06v-.002L9.903 17.505c-.044-.033-.021-.104.034-.104h8.455a.057.057 0 0 0 .054-.04l2.613-8.1z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint6_linear)"></path>
        <path d="M21.06 9.26c.021-.065.098.006.12.072l6.896 21.344.001.006c.01.05-.045.089-.088.06v-.002L9.903 17.505c-.044-.033-.021-.104.034-.104h8.455a.057.057 0 0 0 .054-.04l2.613-8.1z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint7_linear)" fill-opacity=".2"></path>
        <path d="M21.06 9.26c.021-.065.098.006.12.072l6.896 21.344.001.006c.01.05-.045.089-.088.06v-.002L9.903 17.505c-.044-.033-.021-.104.034-.104h8.455a.057.057 0 0 0 .054-.04l2.613-8.1z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint8_linear)" fill-opacity=".3"></path>
        <path d="M17.033 24.138a.559.559 0 0 0-.862.28l-2.018 6.258c-.017.053.043.097.087.064l5.907-4.323-3.114-2.279z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint9_linear)"></path>
        <path d="M17.033 24.138a.559.559 0 0 0-.862.28l-2.018 6.258c-.017.053.043.097.087.064l5.907-4.323-3.114-2.279z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint10_linear)" fill-opacity=".2"></path>
        <path d="M17.033 24.138a.559.559 0 0 0-.862.28l-2.018 6.258c-.017.053.043.097.087.064l5.907-4.323-3.114-2.279z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint11_linear)" fill-opacity=".3"></path>
    </g>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M32.324 17.505c.045-.033.022-.104-.033-.104H25.71c-.38 0-.649.37-.532.73l1.203 3.723 5.943-4.35zm-1.29.364H25.71a.09.09 0 0 0-.087.119l1.005 3.106 4.406-3.225zM21.06 9.26l-2.613 8.101a.057.057 0 0 1-.054.04H9.938c-.055 0-.078.071-.034.104L27.947 30.71l.007.005.034.025.002.001c.042.03.098-.01.087-.059v-.003l-.001-.003-.013-.038L21.18 9.331a.172.172 0 0 0-.018-.04c-.032-.049-.084-.084-.101-.032zm.049 1.375l6.131 18.978-16.045-11.744h7.198c.23 0 .43-.15.5-.364M14.24 30.74c-.044.033-.104-.011-.087-.064l.012-.039 2.006-6.22a.559.559 0 0 1 .862-.279l3.114 2.279-5.907 4.323zm.747-1.127l4.368-3.196-2.598-1.901a.09.09 0 0 0-.14.045l-1.63 5.052z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint12_linear)" fill-opacity=".2"></path>
</svg>
```

How can I turn this into a working .svg? So that it can be used like other svg's? Basically merge mask and symbol together or atleast make it .svg compactible.

Answer (score 2):

Apperantly I can just take out the `<symbol>` and turn it into an `<svg>`but maybe there are different ways masks and symbols can be used, now here, no mask was present I guess.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 42 42" fill="none" id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a">
        <g filter="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_filter0_i)">
            <path d="M13.865 4.666a.936.936 0 0 1 .662-.274h12.924c.249 0 .487.098.662.274l9.14 9.139a.936.936 0 0 1 .273.662V27.39a.936.936 0 0 1-.274.662l-9.139 9.139a.936.936 0 0 1-.662.274H14.527a.936.936 0 0 1-.662-.274l-9.139-9.139a.936.936 0 0 1-.274-.662V14.467c0-.248.099-.487.274-.662l9.14-9.139z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint0_linear)"></path>
        </g>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14.222 4.636l-9.585 9.586v13.556l9.585 9.585h13.556l9.585-9.585V14.222l-9.585-9.586H14.222zM13.447.892c-.497 0-.973.197-1.324.548L1.44 12.122a1.872 1.872 0 0 0-.548 1.324v15.107c0 .497.197.973.548 1.324l10.683 10.682c.35.351.827.549 1.324.549h15.106c.497 0 .973-.198 1.324-.549L40.56 29.877c.35-.351.548-.827.548-1.324V13.446c0-.496-.197-.973-.548-1.324L29.877 1.44a1.872 1.872 0 0 0-1.324-.548H13.446z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint1_linear)"></path>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14.222 4.636l-9.585 9.586v13.556l9.585 9.585h13.556l9.585-9.585V14.222l-9.585-9.586H14.222zM13.447.892c-.497 0-.973.197-1.324.548L1.44 12.122a1.872 1.872 0 0 0-.548 1.324v15.107c0 .497.197.973.548 1.324l10.683 10.682c.35.351.827.549 1.324.549h15.106c.497 0 .973-.198 1.324-.549L40.56 29.877c.35-.351.548-.827.548-1.324V13.446c0-.496-.197-.973-.548-1.324L29.877 1.44a1.872 1.872 0 0 0-1.324-.548H13.446z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint2_linear)" fill-opacity=".3"></path>
        <g filter="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_filter1_d)">
            <path d="M32.324 17.505l-5.943 4.349-1.203-3.722a.559.559 0 0 1 .532-.731h6.58c.056 0 .079.071.034.104z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint3_linear)"></path>
            <path d="M32.324 17.505l-5.943 4.349-1.203-3.722a.559.559 0 0 1 .532-.731h6.58c.056 0 .079.071.034.104z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint4_linear)" fill-opacity=".2"></path>
            <path d="M32.324 17.505l-5.943 4.349-1.203-3.722a.559.559 0 0 1 .532-.731h6.58c.056 0 .079.071.034.104z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint5_linear)" fill-opacity=".3"></path>
            <path d="M21.06 9.26c.021-.065.098.006.12.072l6.896 21.344.001.006c.01.05-.045.089-.088.06v-.002L9.903 17.505c-.044-.033-.021-.104.034-.104h8.455a.057.057 0 0 0 .054-.04l2.613-8.1z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint6_linear)"></path>
            <path d="M21.06 9.26c.021-.065.098.006.12.072l6.896 21.344.001.006c.01.05-.045.089-.088.06v-.002L9.903 17.505c-.044-.033-.021-.104.034-.104h8.455a.057.057 0 0 0 .054-.04l2.613-8.1z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint7_linear)" fill-opacity=".2"></path>
            <path d="M21.06 9.26c.021-.065.098.006.12.072l6.896 21.344.001.006c.01.05-.045.089-.088.06v-.002L9.903 17.505c-.044-.033-.021-.104.034-.104h8.455a.057.057 0 0 0 .054-.04l2.613-8.1z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint8_linear)" fill-opacity=".3"></path>
            <path d="M17.033 24.138a.559.559 0 0 0-.862.28l-2.018 6.258c-.017.053.043.097.087.064l5.907-4.323-3.114-2.279z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint9_linear)"></path>
            <path d="M17.033 24.138a.559.559 0 0 0-.862.28l-2.018 6.258c-.017.053.043.097.087.064l5.907-4.323-3.114-2.279z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint10_linear)" fill-opacity=".2"></path>
            <path d="M17.033 24.138a.559.559 0 0 0-.862.28l-2.018 6.258c-.017.053.043.097.087.064l5.907-4.323-3.114-2.279z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint11_linear)" fill-opacity=".3"></path>
        </g>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M32.324 17.505c.045-.033.022-.104-.033-.104H25.71c-.38 0-.649.37-.532.73l1.203 3.723 5.943-4.35zm-1.29.364H25.71a.09.09 0 0 0-.087.119l1.005 3.106 4.406-3.225zM21.06 9.26l-2.613 8.101a.057.057 0 0 1-.054.04H9.938c-.055 0-.078.071-.034.104L27.947 30.71l.007.005.034.025.002.001c.042.03.098-.01.087-.059v-.003l-.001-.003-.013-.038L21.18 9.331a.172.172 0 0 0-.018-.04c-.032-.049-.084-.084-.101-.032zm.049 1.375l6.131 18.978-16.045-11.744h7.198c.23 0 .43-.15.5-.364M14.24 30.74c-.044.033-.104-.011-.087-.064l.012-.039 2.006-6.22a.559.559 0 0 1 .862-.279l3.114 2.279-5.907 4.323zm.747-1.127l4.368-3.196-2.598-1.901a.09.09 0 0 0-.14.045l-1.63 5.052z" fill="url(#f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint12_linear)" fill-opacity=".2"></path>
        <defs>
            <filter id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_filter0_i" x="4.452" y="4.392" width="33.074" height="34.478" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"></feFlood>
                <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"></feBlend>
                <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"></feColorMatrix>
                <feOffset dy="1.404"></feOffset>
                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=".936"></feGaussianBlur>
                <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"></feComposite>
                <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.45 0"></feColorMatrix>
                <feBlend in2="shape" result="effect1_innerShadow"></feBlend>
            </filter>
            <filter id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_filter1_d" x="7.541" y="7.362" width="27.147" height="26.198" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"></feFlood>
                <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"></feColorMatrix>
                <feOffset dy=".468"></feOffset>
                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.17"></feGaussianBlur>
                <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.9 0"></feColorMatrix>
                <feBlend in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"></feBlend>
                <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"></feBlend>
            </filter>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint0_linear" x1="14.139" y1="4.392" x2="14.139" y2="39.645" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#732600"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#260D00"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#401500"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint1_linear" x1="12.671" y1=".892" x2="29.329" y2="41.108" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#FD6E35"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F50"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint2_linear" x1="-1.82" y1="-2.013" x2="21.114" y2="20.922" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="red"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint3_linear" x1="21.114" y1="9.221" x2="21.114" y2="30.751" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#FD6E35"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F50"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint4_linear" x1="21.114" y1="9.221" x2="21.114" y2="15.54" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#fff"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint5_linear" x1="14.778" y1="5.151" x2="20.733" y2="20.152" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="red"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint6_linear" x1="21.114" y1="9.221" x2="21.114" y2="30.751" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#FD6E35"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F50"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint7_linear" x1="21.114" y1="9.221" x2="21.114" y2="15.54" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#fff"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint8_linear" x1="14.778" y1="5.151" x2="20.733" y2="20.152" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="red"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint9_linear" x1="21.114" y1="9.221" x2="21.114" y2="30.751" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#FD6E35"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#F50"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint10_linear" x1="21.114" y1="9.221" x2="21.114" y2="15.54" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#fff"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint11_linear" x1="14.778" y1="5.151" x2="20.733" y2="20.152" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="red"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="f_icon_1f2d0f1a_paint12_linear" x1="27.901" y1="10.859" x2="14.093" y2="30.751" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#fff"></stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is inline SVG. Under HTML5, `<svg>` is a valid tag, which can be used to add an image (or filter effects, etc.) at that point in the markup. To make this into an SVG file, you only need to do one thing: delete the enclosing `<html>` tag.

You may want to further clean it up by removing the now-extraneous `style` and `id` attributes from the root element, but it isn't strictly necessary. As for the mask and symbol elements, those are valid svg markup, and you can't count on deleting them without changing the way the SVG image will display.